# How do i create a feature in web template?

Tags: feature, feature-activation, feature-receiver, web-template

I have created a web template in visual studio,  it includes the standard element file and onet file, it also has a feature which is scoped to site level.

All this works fine, i can deploy it and can create a subsite based of this template.

I now want to add some code that creates lists etc when the sub site is created (lists are for sub site only).

How would i do this?  I have tried adding another feature to the project which is scoped to web and putting code in this but i get the following error:

"Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Unhandled exception was thrown by the sandboxed code wrapper's Execute method in the partial trust app domain: An unexpected error has occurred."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you use a sandbox solution to solve you issue. But I don't undestand how can it be, because you can not creaate web template as sandbox. I think that you created another project that is contains a new feature. if it is ture, you should select this project and set **sandboxed solution** property to **false** in properties window.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **SPWebEventReceiver** class. This event should fire when a web is created.

```
public class WebProvisionedEventReceiver : SPWebEventReceiver
{
    public override void WebProvisioned(SPWebEventProperties properties) 
    {
        try
        {
            using (SPWeb web = (SPWeb)properties.Web)
            {
```